# Laravel check a laracasts flash message exists

Tags: laravel

I'm using laravel [laracasts / flash](https://github.com/laracasts/flash) flash messages. But I need to validate weather a flash message created before. Is there a way to do this?

I'm creating flash messages like this.

```
flash("This is a message")->success();
```

What I simply want is **to check weather this flash message created before by using an if condition**.

Comment: So, did you try to use `Session::has()`?

Comment: @OlegNurutdinov tried \Session::has('This is a message') but was false even though message there.